# Initialising/Creating Objects through a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

Ok so I'm doing an assignment for my java coursets part I'm stuck at is :

"Implement an operation createparliamentMembers which will create the particular Parliament 
with 80 members."

So i've already created the constructor with it's methods. This is how I wrote the operation to create the objects using the constructor.:

```
public static void createparliamentMembers(){
    Member[] array = new Member[75];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
        if (i < 35) array[i] = new Member(i, "Blue");
        else array[i] = new Member(i,"Red");
        }

    Legislator[] leg = new Legislator[3];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < leg.length; i++){
        leg[i] = new Legislator(i, "Impartial");
    }

    Leader[] lead = new Leader[2];
    for (int t = 0; t < lead.length; t++){
        if (t < 1) lead[t] = new Leader(1, "Red");
        else lead[t] = new Leader(2, "Blue");

    }
```

The problem is the arrays and objects only seem to exist in the operation for creating them and when I try running method of the objects created they don't work because the driver class doesn't recognize the arrays. On the other hand when I use this as just a normal part of the Driver for it runs fine and all methods of the objects work normally.

Edit: Ok so I'm still getting the same problem as before even though i initiliased them outside the createparliamentMembers();

The following code is the Driver im using to test the methods: It keeps saying there is a:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Driver.main(Driver.java:11)
which is the code array[1].FlipCoin(); as im trying to use the method flipcoin from the created objects but it's not working.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
Commands.createparliamentMembers();
array[1].FlipCoin();
}
```

Comment: `" which will create the particular Parliament with 80 members..."` -- Do you have a Parliament class? If so, where is it? Can you add the members to a Parliament object as you create them? What class is the above method in?

Comment: I do have a parliament class it's on it own and contains the methods and constructor for the members of the parliament. The above method was in a seprate class called Commands. I don't understand completely the "Can you add the members to a Parliament object as you create them?" The parliament isn't an object more se then a class containing a constructor and methods for parliament members i want to create.

Comment: Using [naming conventions](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html) can only help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are only defined locally, which means they live and die with the method. When your method finishes, they get put out of memory.

The solution is to define these arrays as instance variables. By that I mean, you need to define the arrays for your class, and then use them in your method:

```
class someClass {
    int[] myArray = new int[2];

    private void someMethod() {
        myArray[0] = 3;
        myArray[1] = //whatever
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not necessarily as his question remains incomplete. He may not even need arrays.

Comment: The question is incomplete, but he makes specific mention of inability to access these arrays from a different class. The logical first step to achieve that is to make the arrays instance members rather than local. I'm not saying that fixes his program, but it answers his question as I understand it.

Comment: Yeah so this finally worked i just needed to call the class that the array was iniatied for the method to work.
I.e The Array was initiated in Commands.java, and the method i want the object to use was flipcoin.
so 
Commands.array[1].flipcoin();

Before i was just trying to use array[1].FlipCoin(); not telling the program where the array was initialized so it didn't find any array in the main.

Answer (score 0):

You state in comment:

> I do have a parliament class it's on it own and contains the methods and constructor for the members of the parliament. The above method was in a seprate class called Commands. I don't understand completely the "Can you add the members to a Parliament object as you create them?" The parliament isn't an object more se then a class containing a constructor and methods for parliament members i want to create.

Parliament isn't an object ***yet***, but you should in fact create one, and in fact your instructions tell you just that: `"which will create the particular Parliament with 80 members..."`. You will need to tell us more about your program's structure and your *specific* requirements, but I suggest:

- First create a Parliament object in the createParliamentMembers method, and call it parliament.
- Then create the members of parliament in that method.
- As you create these members, *add them* to the Parliament object, parliament.
- At the end of the method ***return*** the parliament variable.
- This means that your createParliamentMembers method's signature must change so that rather than return `void` it should be written to return a `Parliament` object.
- When calling the method in the main method, assign what it returns to a Parliament variable that is in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are writing a [*factory method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Create a constructor for Parliament like this:

```
public Parliament(Member[] members, Legislator[] legislators, Leader[] leaders) {
    // do whatever with what's passed in
}
```

Then change your method to return a Parliament object and in the method pass your initialized arrays into the Parliament constructor, like this:

```
// same code as your except the last line
public static Parliament createParliament(){
    Member[] array = new Member[75];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
        if (i < 35) array[i] = new Member(i, "Blue");
        else array[i] = new Member(i,"Red");
        }

    Legislator[] leg = new Legislator[3];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < leg.length; i++){
        leg[i] = new Legislator(i, "Impartial");
    }

    Leader[] lead = new Leader[2];
    for (int t = 0; t < lead.length; t++){
        if (t < 1) lead[t] = new Leader(1, "Red");
        else lead[t] = new Leader(2, "Blue");

    }
    return new Parliament(array, leg, lead);
}
```